# Including a custom native library into a managed UWP application for PInvoking

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, pinvoke, visual-studio-2017

In a UWP application I'm making, I need to include a special version of SQLite, that I compiled from source myself in order to enable features that are not available in the base libraries provided in most systems.

So I have in my Visual Studio solution :

- A Universal Windows C# app (the main app)
- A native C/C++ Universal Windows dynamic library project, with the SQLite amalgamation sources (which compiles correctly)
- A C# Windows Runtime Component library that I reference from the main project for reasons that are outside the scope of this question (but I wanted to mention it exists, just in case)

My question is : **what is the proper way to include the custom SQLite dll into my app's package so it's properly deployed in every supported platform or architecture ?**

Because Visual Studio won't let me reference the SQLite project from the main project, what I did until now is copy the build result (the DLL file) into the main project on a post-build action of the SQLite project, and include this DLL file in the main project with a *Content* build action. This worked fine when running the app on my development computer. However, when I try to run the app in a mobile emulator, I get a `System.DllNotFoundException` because the SQLite DLL cannot be found.

I'm not well versed into the UWP environment specifics, and I'm not finding any documentation about this particular topic (PInvoking in UWP), so if you have any information it would be very mush appreciated :)

Comment: Do you compile your own version of the C++ lib or do/can you use a properly signed binary from the SQLite team?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I use my own. The pre-compiled versions does not expose the set of features I need like R-Tree indexing